# What's this song in Code Geass episode 5?

Tags: music, code-geass

There is a song that starts playing at around 13:04 in episode 5 and lasts for about 20 seconds. It doesn't have any lyrics, and it's not "Stories".

I have been trying to track down this song and am slowly going mad. I haven't been able to find it on any of the official OSTs.

Comment: I deleted my answer as it is not the final answer. I'll post as comment first before finally answering it (since we're still looking for the right answer). Does the insert song you're asking for has lyrics on it or just instrumental? Sorry I have problems connecting to youtube so I really can't hear it.

Comment: And are you sure it's not Stories by Hitomi Kuroishi? Check it's lyrics and you can listen to it to double-check: http://www.animelyrics.com/anime/codegeass/stories.htm

Comment: It doesn't have lyrics nor is it Stories. I just checked.

Comment: It plays from 13:04-13:31. I just checked the OST's for R1 and couldn't find it there; however, that could be because I just listened to the beginning of each song. It is possible that this melody shows up half-way through an OST.

Comment: So far the closest one I have found is [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4ffRYLFmGA4) which has a similar melody.

Comment: After doing some digging around myself and [seeing that other people out there are looking for this song too](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9o2syD50wzQ), I've personally come to the conclusion that the song you are looking for has probably not been officially released. Unfortunately, this means that the official title of this song is not publicly known and that an official full-length instrumental version of this song does not exist publicly. However, I can't definitively state this, hence why this is just a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: @okarin it doesn't actually have to be in R1's OST, Cheese which is the music that plays when C.C is wondering around is found on the 2nd R2 OST track 17 even though it first appears in R1, the same with Eleven (track 6) which plays during one of C.C's monologs

Comment: i just listened to all the OSTs, its not in there

Answer (score 4):

According to the video posted, the song seems to loop at 15 seconds.

If you listen to the song carefully, it sounds like it's just a piano playing, and the tune is something similar to `C -> A -> B -> G -> A -> F -> G -> E`, where it plays one note, then it skips a note and plays the next before going back up to the missed note, and the whole process is repeated.

Now, the song doesn't sound overly complex, so it may have been the reason why it is not included in the OST, regardless of how iconic it is or how many times it's played.

Another possible reason is that this tune has actually been used in some other work outside the anime beforehand. As a result, the production company may have been allowed to use only 15 seconds in the anime as background music, but is forbidden from putting it on soundtracks. My sketchy memory only recalls two other instances where this song is played: when Lelouch is around Nunnaly and when Kallen sees her mother on Refrain. I don't remember the song being any different in those cases, so its exclusion from the OST may have been a licensing issue (allow 15 seconds of the song to be used any number of times, but not allow the song to be reproduced in licensed soundtracks).

Comment: Should point out that i'm not after the bounty or anything and this is from my own investigation froim what i own myself, i am missing about 5 or so Sound Stages and the song may appear in one of these yet i can not confrim that

Comment: I can confirm that this piece of sound is not included in the OST nor in OST2 or closely related sound tracks/opening/ending songs. Your answer of usage is the most plausible answer there is, although quiet allot of people state that its the song Stories by Kuroishi Hitome. But I dont believe that to be the case

Comment: @Dimitrimx it has the same tempo however the background base beat (which i think may be violin or chello) more follows the loop of C -> C -> B -> B -> A -> A -> B -> B where it plays one note twice before dropping down and repeating this process until it gets to as low as desired before it reverses the process

Answer (score 2):

Found [a playlist on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLb4mticUuCmQSnQpXJDttkzbhOxAdnGWf) that includes all the tracks excluded from the OST.

The track you are looking for is "Out of the Ordinary". It is [the 5th video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bDQuknKy0ZU) in the playlist I mentioned before.